# Optimization of a complex multiple join query in Oracle

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I want to optimize an old query I did not write myself. My problem is I am not used to this kind of joins, with old school (+) and multiple clauses between two tables. For the moment, the query takes about 15 minutes to execute as there is a lot of rows in each table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM A, B, C, D, E, F, G
WHERE A.id = B.id
  AND C.id = B.id
  AND A.daytime >= C.daytime
  AND (C.end_date IS NULL OR A.daytime < C.end_date)
  AND A.id = D.id(+)
  AND A.daytime = D.daytime(+)
  AND A.id = E.id
  AND A.daytime = E.daytime(+)
  AND A.id = F.id
  AND A.daytime = F.daytime(+)
  AND custom_function(A.id, 'O', A.daytime) = G.id(+)
  AND A.daytime = G.daytime(+)
  AND A.classname IN('X','Y','Z');
```

I do not expect someone to rewrite the query for me, but just to guide me:

- Can I optimize such a query ?
- If so, should I use multiple subqueries ?

I tried a complex set of inner and outer join but I cannot manage to really understand what I am doing.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***

Actually the problem comes from the `SELECT` clause, because I'm not using `SELECT *` in the real query, but a bunch of external functions applied to the columns, and they are the reason for the time needed for execution. Thank you everyone but there is no solution to my problem.

Comment: Rewriting to explicit `join` syntax is good, but won't help performance. I would start looking at the `custom_function`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Ok, that's what I feared. I cannot touch to this function. Therefore the query is already optimal right ?

Comment: The query looks pretty straightforward, but you should check the execution plan.

Comment: @HoneyBadger `custom_function` does not seem to have any impact on the execution

Comment: In that case you need to go back to the execution plan to see what can be done.

Comment: Consider what @HoneyBadger has said; using explicit `INNER`/`LEFT OUTER` `JOIN` is a very good suggestion: the syntax `SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.field = B.field(+)` is not always equivalent to `SELECT * FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.field = B.field` for more than 2 tables joined using more than 1 field for each. To me, `A.id = E.id` (without the `(+)`) followed by `A.daytime = E.daytime(+)` does not look like something anyone would like to do.

Answer (score 1):

The only parameters to your call to `custom_function` come from A.

The number of calls will probably be reduced if you do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT A.* (SELECT custom_function(id, 'O', daytime) FROM dual) AS cf FROM A WHERE classname IN('X','Y','Z')
) A_Alias
, B, C, D, E, F, G
WHERE A_Alias.id = B.id
  AND C.id = B.id
  AND A_Alias.daytime >= C.daytime
  AND (C.end_date IS NULL OR A_Alias.daytime < C.end_date)
  AND A_Alias.id = D.id(+)
  AND A_Alias.daytime = D.daytime(+)
  AND A_Alias.id = E.id
  AND A_Alias.daytime = E.daytime(+)
  AND A_Alias.id = F.id
  AND A_Alias.daytime = F.daytime(+)
  AND A_Alias.cf = G.id(+)
  AND A_Alias.daytime = G.daytime(+);
```

This will reduce the count by both removing the record-multiplying effect of the `JOIN` and by making sure as many rows as possible are filtered out from A (condition on `classname`).

**Note**: I have also included an optimization from [here.](http://%20oracle-base.com/articles/misc/efficient-function-calls-from-sql)
It may have no effect but is worth testing.
Search for sections called: **Scalar Subquery Caching** & **Scalar Subquery Caching (Revisited)** (I invite you to read the entire thing).

Comment: Hi, I've tried your suggestion which seemed really fine, but the query takes exactly the same time unfortunately. However thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Actually, the query takes the same time whether or not `AND custom_function(A.id, 'O', A.daytime) = G.id(+)` is present

Comment: Just seen your comment (the real query is a SELECT with external functions). Are you sure, even in this case, you cannot call them from sub-queries (= **before** you multiply records in your JOIN)? Condition for it to be applicable: they are deterministic (= when called with the same parameters, the result will never change) + they have no side effect (= whether you call them once or 1k times, the post-condition of your system is unchanged) + the parameters passed come from 1 table or a least a subset of all the tables you need.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I removed 80% of the columns I didn't really need, and my query takes now 7x less time to execute: that was my need. Really thank you very much for the time you passed trying to help.